# How to access generated types in nuxt plugin?

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-module

I'm building a nuxt module with type generation. In a module, I want to generate types, add them to `.nuxt/types/`, and then use them in the plugin to pass them to the generic function. How can i do this?

I want something like this:

```
// module.ts

export default defineNuxtModule({
  meta: {
   // ...
  },
  defaults: {
   // ...
  },
  setup(_options, nuxt) {
    addTypeTemplate({
      filename: 'foo-types.d.ts',
      getContents: () => `type TypeForGeneric = Record<string, unknown>`,
    })

    nuxt.hook('prepare:types', async ({ references }) => {
      references.push({ path: resolve(nuxt.options.buildDir, 'types/foo-types.d.ts') })
    })
    
    addPlugin(resolve('./runtime/plugin'))
  },
})
```

```
// runtime/plugin.ts

import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
import type { TypeForGeneric } from '' // <= where can I import it from?

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const fooWithTypes = foo<TypeForGeneric>()

  return {
    provide: {
      fooWithTypes,
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm struggling getting my module types exposed as well, and I've not seen a consistent way to do this across all modules yet.
But I did manage to get a file written in the .nuxt/types dir by using the addTypeTemplate function: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/kit/templates#examples-1

You should then be able to import your type from '#imports'

Comment: Hrm, I still can't find a way to have it imported without pointing to the full module path either.
The content of my template file is something like: 'export * from "my-api/dist/runtime/types/users.d.ts";'
And it's written to '.nuxt/types/my-api.d.ts' but the types can only be found in '~~/my-api/dist/runtime/types/users' which defeats the purpose of providing the types file